# how can use customized listview

Tags: android

Hi 
how i can use custom listview with textview and imageview.i tried following code

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
  this.getListView().setCacheColorHint(00000000);
  String[] data = new String[] { "aac", "xsfdf", "dsf", "frgr" };
  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.TextView01};
   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
           this,null,R.layout.newimage,data, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

but it is not working.
Help me.
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in not the way to use custom listview , Here u need to create custom adapter
Refer this [example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/)